# How to sort and join files in linux with huge data and print blank values for the values which are not found

Tags: linux, shell-script

Consider the below files :

file1:

```
1

2

3

4
```

file2:

```
2

3

6

9
```

expected output:

```
1 NULL

2 2

3 3

4 NULL

NULL 6

NULL 9
```

I have tried `paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t/\0\t/g' | column -s $'\t' -t` and it dint give me as i expected.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried : 

paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t/\0\t/g' | column -s $'\t' -t 

But dint work , as per my requirement

Comment: It would be much appreciated if i get a script  :)

Comment: M actually a new bee to linux !!!

Comment: @Nahdnivog are the input files sorted? And could you please put what you've tried in question

Comment: @ bob : Yes in put is sorted only

Comment: Since you are a "new bee", here's some advice. 1. When posting a question: state what you have tried, and why you think your approach did not work. 2. Format your question properly using the tools available (code should be in code tags). 3. Read [this](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Best regards.

Comment: @maulinglawns:  Thanks for your words , will follow it up , kindly help me on my requirements it is bit urgent :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since being a newbee you could try to achieve this with simpler bash commands (not `sed` which has a lot of options). Try reading the two files line by line for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

command comm can give you the results you need in a close format to your requirement. In my system comm (GNU coreutils) 8.25 is installed by default.
I have created two files b and c txt including your data plus more numbers for testing.

```
comm --nocheck-order b.txt c.txt #(or file1.txt file2.txt)
```

Output :

```
1
                2
                3
4
        6
8
                9
        10
        11
                13
                16
        17
18
                19
20
22
```

1st column includes entries from file 1 without match on file 2.

2nd column indicates entries from file 2 without match on file 1.

3rd column indicates common / matched entries in file 1 and 2

Although your files are sorted, for some reason comm complains about unsorted files. Can be solved using the --nocheck-order switch.

The list can be formatted using a custom delimiter (see man comm).

Since you have built your list, you can manipulate it like this:

```
readarray data < <(comm --nocheck-order --output-delimiter "-"  b.txt c.txt)
for ((i=0;i<${#data[@]};i++)); do
va=$(grep -e "-" <<<"${data[$i]}")
if [[ $va == "" ]]; then
    echo ${data[$i]} " null"
elif [[ $va == "--"* ]]; then 
        data2=$(echo ${data[$i]} | grep -Po '[0-9]*')
        echo $data2 " " $data2
else
    data2=$(echo ${data[$i]} | grep -Po '[0-9]*')
    echo "null " $data2
fi
done
```

Other interesting commands is join and sdiff, but comm was the closest.
Also you can have a look in this post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/515900/how-to-compare-two-files

Regards

Comment: Thanks guys :) i figgured a simple solution :) using if else :) :)

Comment: file1="/tmp/A/file1"
file2="/tmp/A/file2"
output_file="/tmp/A/file3"
yes | rm -f $output_file
for field1 in `cat $file1`
do
field2=`grep $field1 $file2`
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
echo "$field1,$field2" >> $output_file
else
echo "$field1,null" >> $output_file
fi
done

Comment: You could post the solution as an "edit" in your main question or as an answer  to view the code with a kind of format....