# Compare two files and print matches in the first file adding extra column

Tags: file-comparison

I have two different files with one column each. The file 1 has more info and I want a command to search the matches against the file 2 and then return the original file 1 with an extra column saying for example "match"

File 1

```
Mg_134
Mg_560
```

File 2

```
Mg_1
Mg_134
```

Output

```
Mg_134 match
Mg_560
```

I tried to use join and grep -Ff, but I would like to have this specific output. Thanks

Comment: try sdiff or comm and also see this post : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325087/how-to-sort-and-join-files-in-linux-with-huge-data-and-print-blank-values-for-th/325207#325207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be a pretty standard task for `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $1 in a {$2="match"}1' File2 File1
Mg_134 match
Mg_560
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files are sorted, [the standard tool for this is `comm`:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html)

```
comm -2 file1 file2
```

The `-2` option is to suppress printing lines unique to `file2`.

It doesn't give the *exact* format you specify.  However, you can parse it to give that output if you like.  (Standard tools and standard formats are usually pretty well thought out.)

Comment: Did not work, I sorted the files using "sort -V" and I got the same number of lines of the file 1, and the messages: comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order

Comment: @Clarissa, `sort -V` is a GNU extension, not standard.  That doesn't count as being actually sorted.  See the specs for `comm` as linked to from my answer.